# Programmatically populate form fields (send keystrokes, etc.)

Tags: list-form

I have thousands of documuments with associated metadata to upload to a library. Unfortunately I do not have the option of writing a program using the Server or Client Object Models, but I would still like to automate the process to the extent possible. I thought that I might use the Win32 API to populate the form controls and then submit the form, but the controls don't seem to have window handles, or I can't find them with Spy++.

Is it possible to programmatically populate form controls?

Comment: Have you tried automating SharePoint Designer, instead of the web interface? If you can't do it via the Win32 API, perhaps you could use image recognition to find the right place to move the mouse and click. AutoHotkey [supports this](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm), and there are even image-recognition tools out there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but the users will not have SharePoint Designer. They will have only a browser. Even if image recognition helps me to click on a field, how would I set the text?

Comment: From your question, I assumed you were talking about a one-time upload by a single user (yourself). Perhaps a little more context would help?

Comment: The uploaders are regular users, i.e., not administartors or developers. A CSV file was prepared like this: Ahmad,Zia,...,Ahmad_Zia_001_blah-blah-blah.pdf with fields first_name, last_name, etc, and the last field is the \path\to\the\file.pdf. This was done on the assumption that they would be able to programmatically load that file into SharePoint but it seems that that option will not be available. I have to use a custom form that has some logic behind the scenes, and I am looking for a way to fill out the form without typing everything again.

Comment: There are web-automation tools, like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and Phantom. However, if you already know CSOM, that would be easier than learning a new framework. You may be able to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for this (as mentioned above), but it still requires learning a new language.

Comment: OTOH, your basic question "Is it possible to programmatically populate form controls?" is not necessarily related to SharePoint, and may find useful, generic answers on [SO].

Comment: "I have to use a custom form ..." Do you mean, your users need to upload using a custom form? Or are you (the developer) doing a one-time automation of the form? If your users need to use it directly, then the non-SharePoint solutions I've suggested will probably require some training, as well as development work. CSOM can be integrated behind-the-scenes on the form page; and I'm not aware of another integrated solution.

Comment: Programmatically manipulating forms is not necessarily SharePoint-specific. I asked her because I was unable to find the control window handles using Spy++. Maybe I am doing something wrong or maybe they are not windows. In the latter case I cannot use SetWindowText  etc.

Comment: I meaan that my users must use a custom form because the form has som elogiv behnd it that does various things such as enforcing naming convention

Comment: The form has some logic behind it.

Comment: Web UIs are typically not exposed in the UI of the browser, but they *are* exposed to JS running on the page, via the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). You could add custom JS to the page, to fill out the form. You could receive the CSV as a file upload, or simply copy-n-paste.

Comment: Are you saying that the form displayed by SharePoint is, in fact, not a regular window with child controls, each having a window handle? I will investigate Copy/paste (with my program doing the copying) and/or AutoHotkey as you suggested earlier.

Comment: If you're talking about a form on a webpage (SharePoint or not), then yes, it does not have child controls. Or, in other words, the control to which a web page is rendered does not have child controls. You can certainly send keystrokes, though; perhaps simply tabbing through the page would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps to upload the documents in bulk to SharePoint 2013 with associated metadata.

1. Create the required metadata columns in the library. Example "First Name" and "Last Name".
2. Upload the documents using "Open with Explorer" option in Library ribbon.
3. Confirm the data in metadata columns.

Sample metadata columns in an Excel document

[image]

and here is the outcome after uploading to a library. The First and Last names come automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that:  
1) The metadata is in a CSV file like Ahmad,Zia,...,Ahmad_Zia_001.pdf.

Comment: 1) The documents are PDF and the metadata is in a CSV file like Ahmad,Zia,...,Ahmad_Zia_001_blah-blah-blah.pdf and  
2) I *must* use the form because the form chooses the location (your files go to the "Z" library and the Ahmad_Zia_001 folder (001 is your unique ID). It also constructs the filename from the metadata.

Comment: @Anonymous, as the structural data is in the CSV file it can only be done using some custom code. The CSV can be read by System.IO and then you need to call CSOM or a server object model APIs to upload PDFs to the library. I would suggest you to create a simple console application to accomplish this. I am not sure if there are third party solutions out there to achieve this.

Comment: Actually I have already written a working console program. For various reasons I will probably not be able to use it at this client so I was looking for a way to save my colleagues from typing everything that they already typed again.

Comment: @Anonymous, by the way what type of form is it? Is it an HTML form? In your console app, you can submit the form programmatically in a loop. Also just clarifying do you have that CSV (metadata) ready?

Comment: To be honest I have never seen the custom form. Right now I am trying to manipulate the regular form that appears when you edit a document's properties. Yes, the CS?V file exists and I can load it into a SharePoint site on my computer.